# Functions intersection approximation

Tags: python-3.x, numeric, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis, numerical-computing

Let f1 and f2 be two functions in the range of [a, b], and maxerr the required approximation. They both differentiable and continuous in this range. I should return an iterable of approximate intersection Xs, such that:
∀x∈Xs, |f_1(x) - f_2(x)| < maxerr.

The signature of the function for example should be:

```
def intersection(self, f1: callable, f2: callable, a: float, b: float, maxerr=0.001) -> callable:
```

**What is the most profficient way to do that without using a library method that finds the intersection directly?**

Notes:

- Python 3.7
- Forbidden build-in functions: finding roots and intersections of functions, interpolation, integration, matrix decomposition, eigenvectors and solving linear systems.

Right now my code is as the following:

```
def intersection_recursive(f1, f2, a, b, maxerr, X, start_time, timeout, side_flag):
  f = f1 - f2
    startX = a
    endX = b
    while not f(startX) * f(endX) < 0 and time.time() < start_time + timeout:
        startX = random.uniform(a, b)
        endX = random.uniform(startX, b)
    mid = (startX + endX) / 2
    while not abs(f(mid)) < maxerr and time.time() < start_time + timeout:
        if f(startX) * f(mid) < -1:
            endX = mid
        else:
            startX = mid
        mid = (startX + endX) / 2
    if abs(f(mid)) < maxerr:
        X.append(mid)
    else:
        return X
    if side_flag:
        return intersection_recursive(f1, f2, a, mid, maxerr, X, start_time, timeout, not side_flag)
    else:
        return intersection_recursive(f1, f2, mid, b, maxerr, X, start_time, timeout, not side_flag)

def intersection(self, f1: callable, f2: callable, a: float, b: float, maxerr=0.001) -> callable:
   timeout = 10
   X = []
   start_time = time.time()
   intersection_recursive(f1, f2, a, b, maxerr, X, start_time, timeout, True)
   return X
```

Comment: Without any additional information about the functions the no free lunch theorem applies and any search strategy is as valid as any other.

Comment: without knowing more about f1 and f2, their difference could be as large as you want

Comment: @AviFerdman That's a completely different question...

Comment: And lets say they both differentiable and continuous, how can I improve it? @orlp

Answer (score 0):

The below answer is to the original question, where no assumptions about the functions are made...

---

Without any additional information about the functions the no free lunch theorem applies and any search strategy is as valid as any other.

That said, a [simple quasirandom sequence](http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/) covers all of `[a, b]` uniformly at every detail level, given enough time.

I don't think your function signature is correct by the way, it should return an iterable.

```
from typing import Callable, Iterable

def intersection(f1: Callable[[float], float],
                 f2: Callable[[float], float],
                 a: float, b: float,
                 maxerr: float=0.001) -> Iterable[float]:
   a, b = sorted([a, b])
   invphi = 2 / (1 + 5**0.5)
   t = 0.5
   while True:
       x = a + (b-a)*t
       if abs(f1(x) - f2(x)) < maxerr:
           yield x
       t = (t + invphi) % 1.0
```

Comment: I got the idea, but lets say they differentiable and continuous. How should I implement it now? @orlp